# Android xml after moving to code doesnt work

Tags: java, android, xml, view

After direct recreation of the XML code of the view to the java code, it stops working properly.

The XML code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.virviil.splashscreen.MainActivity">


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.7" />
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" />
</TableLayout>
```

And the java code is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TableLayout activity_main = new TableLayout(this);
    activity_main.setId(R.id.activity_main);
    LayoutParams layout_439 = new LayoutParams(0,0);
    layout_439.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    layout_439.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    activity_main.setLayoutParams(layout_439);

    TableRow tableRow_879 = new TableRow(this);
    LayoutParams layout_311 = new LayoutParams(0,0);
    layout_311.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    layout_311.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    layout_311.weight = 0.7f;
    tableRow_879.setLayoutParams(layout_311);
    activity_main.addView(tableRow_879);

    TableRow tableRow_600 = new TableRow(this);
    tableRow_600.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    LayoutParams layout_61 = new LayoutParams(0,0);
    layout_61.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    layout_61.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    tableRow_600.setLayoutParams(layout_61);

    ProgressBar progressBar_343 = new ProgressBar(this);
    LayoutParams layout_81 = new LayoutParams(0,0);
    layout_81.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    layout_81.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    progressBar_343.setLayoutParams(layout_81);
    tableRow_600.addView(progressBar_343);
    activity_main.addView(tableRow_600);

    TableRow tableRow_315 = new TableRow(this);
    LayoutParams layout_574 = new LayoutParams(0,0);
    layout_574.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    layout_574.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    layout_574.weight = 0.3f;
    tableRow_315.setLayoutParams(layout_574);
    activity_main.addView(tableRow_315);

    setContentView(activity_main);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

The idea is to programmable change the vertival aligment of the progress.
So, in XML it works[image]
And in JAVA - not.

Comment: put it in Linearlayout

Comment: But xml works. So even i'll change everything to linearLayout, why the java doesn't work?

Comment: TableLayout activity_main = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity);

Comment: I don't use xml at all. That's the point

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need is to pay more attention and use LinearLayout instead od TableLayout for the whole xml view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.virviil.splashscreen.MainActivity">
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

....
```

Comment: That does nothing. I added everything into linearLayout - but that's still doesnt working